# MYSQL ERROR not showing correctly in Class Function

Tags: php, mysql

```
$conn = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);    
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (email,password) VALUES ('user@example.com','asdfasdfasdfsadf')";
    if($conn->query($sql) != true){
        echo $conn->error;
        // Its display correct result, Duplicate entry 'user@example.com' for key 'email'
    }
```

here $conn->error; shows correct result but in below class its not showing anything

**But Problem is**

```
    <?php
class db
{
  private $host;
  private $user;
  private $pass;
  private $dbname;
}
class conn extends db
{
  public function connect()
  {
    $this->host = "localhost";
    $this->user = "root";
    $this->pass = "";
    $this->dbname = "jobportal";
    $conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
    return $conn;
  }
}


class work extends conn
{

 public function insert_user($email, $password_hash)
  {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (email,password) VALUES ('user@example.com','asdfasdf')";
    if ($this->connect()->query($sql) == TRUE) {
      echo 'inserted';
    } else {
      return $this->connect()->error;
      // Return Blank No Result it returns, As its duplicated value it it will insert , so it will show error as duplicate.
    }
  }
}

$obj = new work;
echo $obj->insert_user('user@example.com', 'asdfasdf');
```

Here in error it's not showing anything, just blank;
where problem can anyone help me?

Comment: change `echo $this->connect()->error;` to   `return  $this->connect()->error;` so `$insertResponse = insert_user();` should get the error.

Comment: I tried it already, but nothing show,  $this->connect()->error; this return no msg

Comment: I suspect the problem lies in the way you're using the parent class methods, but you haven't posted the parent class so it's impossible to say.

Comment: What does `function connect()` look like? Singleton?

Comment: here connect function for mysqli connection , see here full code https://prnt.sc/10he6mz

Comment: No. Post the relevant code **in the question**. Use the "Edit" button, and  don't post an image.

Comment: code updated, u can check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `connect()` method in your `conn` class creates a new connection every time you call it. In your `insert_user()` method you call `connect()` to run the query, then call it again to find the error. The new connection you're using to find the error is separate from the connection used to run the query, so there's no error to be found.

Additionally, creating a new connection for every new query without closing them is likely to exhaust the connection limit. You should create one connection and re-use that every time.

Below is a revised version of your code.
Notes:

- MySQLi is set to throw exceptions if it encounters an error. These exceptions are trapped and reported in the `try...catch` block.
- I've changed your code to use a prepared statement to avoid SQL injection.
- Your database parameters are passed into the `Work` constructor

```
    class Conn           // No parent db class - it serves no purpose
                         // Class names begin with capitals, by convention
    {
    
        private $host;   // Local copies of database credentials. Not really needed
        private $user;
        private $pass;
        private $dbname;
    
        // Set up the database connection in the constructor.
        public function __construct(string $host, string $user, string $password, string $dbname) {
            $this->host = $host;
            $this->user = $user;
            $this->pass = $password;
            $this->dbname = $dbname;
    
            // Set mysqli to throw exceptions on error
            mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

            // open a connection for later use
            $this->conn = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
        }
    }
    
    class Work extends Conn
    {
    
        public function insert_user(string $email, string $password_hash)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO user (email,password) VALUES (?,?)";
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $password_hash);
            $stmt->execute();
            return;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    try {
        $obj = new Work("server", "username", "password", "schema");
        $obj->insert_user('user@example.com', 'asdfasdf');
        echo "inserted";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: This code is working fine. How can I use this $obj in another PHP file? like I want to call  $obj->insert_user('user@example.com', 'asdfasdf'); from another PHP file like process.php

Comment: @user7252501 Put the code in a separate file and `include` it in whichever files need it. It's common practice to use an [autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to load classes.